# How to remove the "vinyl record" from the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens

On my Android phone I see a picture of a moving vinyl record when I press the on/off button.
It seems to be a media player application. But I don't want to use it. I don't even have any music saved on my phone. And I don't find any setting to remove it.

[image]

How can I remove this?
I want to see the clock and maybe other things on the lock screen.

Comment: Lock screens are usually customized by their makers. Could you mention your phone model, Android version, and whether you're using a stock lock screen or a 3rd-party one?

Answer (score 0):

Force Stop the music app in the Settings. Hope it works.

Comment: I found an app with the name "music", but I didn't find a place to disable it or to (force) shut it down. When I open the Music app it asks me to agree to their Terms of Service. Until now I did not agree. It shouldn't play...

Comment: There always is a Force Stop function in apps on android phones.